# Diferencia entre @yield e @include en Blade de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Hola gente quería saber si hay alguna diferencia técnica, en principio y para la función que les doy, estarían funcionando igual.

Parece mas claro usar `@include`. pero quisiera saber si hay algún detalle que deba saber para no abusar de él.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@yield` va a buscar una sección establecida en la página (o vista) actual y la va a mostrar en ese lugar, se le puede agregar también un valor por defecto en caso que no haya nada en dicha sección.

Así `@yield('titulo', 'Mi sitio')` va a incluir lo que esté definido en `@section Blog @endsection` en una vista (el texto Blog en este caso), si no hay nada definido, va a mostrar el texto Mi sitio.

El código fuente de @yield es:

```
protected function compileYield($expression)
{
    return "<?php echo \$__env->yieldContent{$expression}; ?>";
}

public function yieldContent($section, $default = '')
{
    $sectionContent = $default;

    if (isset($this->sections[$section])) {
        $sectionContent = $this->sections[$section];
    }

    $sectionContent = str_replace('@@parent', '--parent--holder--', $sectionContent);

    return str_replace(
        '--parent--holder--', '@parent', str_replace('@parent', '', $sectionContent)
    );
}
```

---

`@include` va a incluir simplemente otra vista en la actual, de forma tal que `@include('blog.articulo')` va a buscar el archivo `views\blog\articulo.blade.php` y lo va a incluir en la vista actual, todo su contenido.

El código de fuente de @include es:

```
protected function compileInclude($expression)
{
    if (Str::startsWith($expression, '(')) {
        $expression = substr($expression, 1, -1);
    }

    return "<?php echo \$__env->make($expression, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que yo veo como diferencia es cómo se implementa en el código, por ejemplo.

Si tienes un `@include` al igual que implementar en **PHP** es que solo es para un código en específico que lo llamas desde otro sitio, en cambio el `@yield` le pones un "nombre" por decirlo de alguna manera. Es decir, `@yield('contenido')` y ese contenido lo puedes mostrar desde otras vistas que esten referenciado a ese `@yield`.

Obviamente que en código le haces la extensión a donde está ese `yield`.

Así es como yo lo veo. El `@yield`para muchas llamadas y el `@include` para una sola en especifico.